# In Rust what is the idiomatic way to run a side effect (such as logging) if Result is Err

Tags: rust

From a `Result`, I would like to run a side effect on it if it's an `Err` (like logging the error) and return the error, what's the most idiomatic to do it?

I could do this:

```
fn do_something() -> Result<(), MyError> {...}

fn foo() -> Result<(), MyError> {
  do_something()
    .map_err(|err| { 
      println!("Got error in Foo: {:#?}", err);
      err
    })?;
  ...
}
```

But I am not a big fan of this, as this feels like a misuse of `map_xxx`: I am doing a side-effect on a `map...` function, and I am not even mapping the error to something else.

I guess this would make the side effect more obvious:

```
let result =  do_something();
if let Err(err) = result {
  println!("Got error in Foo: {:#?}", err);
  return Err(err);
}
...
```

But I find it verbose. Ideally I would be looking to something like

```
do_something()
  .if_err(|err| {println!("Got error in Foo: {:#?}", err);})?;
```

Comment: There is a proposal for an [`inspect_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.inspect_err) method, but currently it's just that, a proposal. So you can either use one of the existing solutions, or add your own method via an extension trait, à la [`result-inspect`](https://crates.io/crates/result-inspect).

Comment: Sure, the name of the function suggests that you're mapping the error and it would be better to have a more fitting name, but no one is going to look at this type of code and be confused. I would almost always prefer doing what you're doing than to pull in another dependency or rely on unstable/experimental features.

Comment: @Masklinn It's a lot more than just a proposal. The stabilization PR has been merged in back November, and based on the attached milestone, this can be expected to become stable in 1.76.0, i.e. the next version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Rust Nightly, the [`inspect_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.inspect_err) method can be used.

```
do_something().inspect_err(|err| println!("Got error in Foo: {err:#?}"))?;
```

Answer (score 3):

You want [`tap_err()`](https://docs.rs/tap/latest/tap/trait.TapFallible.html#tymethod.tap_err) from the [`tap`](https://crates.io/crates/tap) crate:

```
do_something().tap_err(|err| {
    println!("Got error in Foo: {:#?}", err);
})?;
```

The same crate provides method for similar inspection of `Option`, as well as values in general.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout great [tap](https://crates.io/crates/tap) library! It has a generic [Tap](https://docs.rs/tap/1.0.1/tap/trait.Tap.html) trait which allows you to "inspect" value. For example:

```rust
use tap::tap::Tap;

let end = make_value()
  // this line has no effect on the rest of the code
  .tap(|v| log!("The produced value was: {}", v))
  .process_value();
```

And in the case of inspecting only errors of `Result`, you can use [TapFallible](https://docs.rs/tap/1.0.1/tap/trait.TapFallible.html). For example its [tap_err](https://docs.rs/tap/1.0.1/tap/trait.TapFallible.html#tymethod.tap_err) method:

```rust
use tap::TapFallible;

fn foo() -> Result<(), ()> { todo!() }

fn bar() {
    let val = foo()
        .tap_err(|err| log!("error: {}", err))
        .process_value();
}
```